# An application using a windows account to access a directory

Tags: c#, active-directory, user-accounts

There is a directory on a file_server, which can be accessable from AD account -> TRacc,

I am tring to write an application which will be working on an application_server and using the TRacc account to access this directory and put some files into it.

So how to associate an windows account with a c# application

Comment: You will need to start a new process and provide the Username & Password for the Tracc account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways of doing this.

1). Build your app in C#, and when you go to launch it, Hold "Shift" and right click the *.exe file and select "Run As". You will be prompted for Your Username, Password & Domain. Use the Tracc account details and your app will work fine.

2). Create a Process within your application. Provide the Username, Secure Password and Domain for the process.

I would go with option 1. As hard coding the password details into your app means anyone running it can perform tasks, which isn't good.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Since my application will run in server, it will be an automated application and that way I can use scheduled tasks, I checked it and saw that it is possible to run an application with an ad account. Thanks for giving me a tip to find what I need.

Comment: Yeah, you can select the Account to use in Scheduled Tasks, if i'd know that's what you would be doing I would have suggested it. :-)